# How are related banners used with promotions?

Tags: magento-enterprise, promotions

Documentation of this feature is very sparse. Basically, I want the ability to dynamically display a banner on the cart/checkout pages when a certain product is in the cart. Is this what related banners are for? If not, what is their function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Banners and promotions work as such:

- Banners can be associated to Promotions, and displayed only when a promotion is active
- Banners can be associated, via a promotion, to a customer segment

From the Magento EE User Guide:

> **Related Promotions** – This tab includes one grid containing all your existing Shopping Cart Price Rules, and one grid containing all
>   your existing Catalog Price Rules. Select the checkbox next to a Price
>   Rule to associate it. **You can associate this Banner to multiple
>   Shopping Cart and Catalog Price Rules simultaneously**. If the Banner is
>   associated to any price rules, **it will only display when that rule is
>   applied** (the price rule is active and the conditions in the rule have
>   been met). You can also associate a Banner to a Price Rule via the
>   Price Rule page. For both Shopping Cart and Catalog Price Rules, there
>   is now a Related Banners tab in the Price Rule page. This tab includes
>   a grid containing all existing Banners, which can be associated by
>   selecting the checkbox next to the Banner.

And from the section regarding customer segmentation:

> **Banners** – To associate a Segment to a Banner, navigate to CMS > Banners, click Add Banner or select an existing Banner from the grid,
>   and select **Specified from the Customer Segments** dropdown. This
>   will open a multi-select menu including all existing Segments. *You
>   can associate multiple Segments to a Banner*.

Comment: OK, for example let's say I have a cart promotion where if productA is in the cart, productB and productC are eligible for a discount if they're added to the same order. In order to advertise that promotion I would actually have to create a separate promotion with related banner that only required productA to be in the cart but applied no discount. In other words, the full ruleset has to be satisfied in order for a related banner to display. Does that make sense and is it correct?

Comment: Correct - but what I have done is create dummy rules with no discounts for banner display only, specifically for means of promoting upsells.

Comment: I think we're saying the same thing, or did I get something wrong in my first comment?

Comment: Ha, no you're right - I misread it. We're on the same page.

Comment: So, if I read correctly: [ Promotions > Price Rule > Related banners ]  and [ CMS > Banners > Related Promotions] accomplish exactly the same thing, or is there a difference in the business logic they apply?